# DjangoCMS - multiple sites with shared pages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm trying to build several websites with `DjangoCMS` with some shared pages. Is it possible to create a page which is shared across all django `Site`s?

With a basic `DjangoCMS` configuration, when a page is published on a `Site` it does not appear on other `Site`. I am wondering if this is configurable in any way.

When looking at the code I've seen that the `TreeNode` is linked to a specific `Site` (https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L52), so I guess that if it's possible it won't be that simple.

```py
class TreeNode(MP_Node):
    # [...]
    site = models.ForeignKey(
        Site,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("site"),
        related_name='djangocms_nodes',
        db_index=True,
    )
    # [...]
```

I'd be fine with an external module if DjangoCMS does not handle this, or even some ideas or lead of how to approach this, I really don't have a clue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue with some ugly patches in the DjangoCMS code itself.

```py
from cms import cms_menus
from cms.templatetags import cms_tags
from cms.utils import page


# Ugly-patching DjangoCMS so that a page from another Django Site can be displayed
def new_get_page_from_path(site, path, preview=False, draft=False):
    """
    Resolves a url path to a single page object.
    Returns None if page does not exist
    """
    from cms.models import Title

    titles = Title.objects.select_related('page__node')
    published_only = not draft and not preview

    if draft:
        titles = titles.filter(publisher_is_draft=True)
    elif preview:
        titles = titles.filter(publisher_is_draft=False)
    else:
        titles = titles.filter(published=True, publisher_is_draft=False)
    titles = titles.filter(path=(path or ''))
    titles = list(titles.iterator())

    for title in titles:
        if title.page.node.site_id != site.pk:
            continue

        if published_only and not page._page_is_published(title.page):
            continue

        title.page.title_cache = {title.language: title}
        return title.page

    # This is the different part from the DjangoCMS code:
    #    re do the same loop, but this time ignore the Site filtering
    for title in titles:
        if published_only and not page._page_is_published(title.page):
            continue

        title.page.title_cache = {title.language: title}
        return title.page
    return


# Ugly-patching DjangoCMS so that a page from another Django Site can fetched
# using {% pageurl %} (for example)
def new_get_page_queryset(site, draft=True, published=False):
    from cms.models import Page

    if draft:
        pages = Page.objects.drafts().on_site(site)
        if pages:
            return pages

    if published:
        pages = Page.objects.public().published(site)
        if pages:
            return pages

    pages = Page.objects.public().on_site(site)
    if pages:
        return pages

    # This is the different part from the DjangoCMS code:
    #    re do the same logic, but this time ignore the Site filtering

    if draft:
        return Page.objects.drafts()

    if published:
        return Page.objects.public().published()
    return Page.objects.public()


page.get_page_from_path = new_get_page_from_path
page.get_page_queryset = new_get_page_queryset
cms_tags.get_page_queryset = new_get_page_queryset
cms_menus.get_page_queryset = new_get_page_queryset
```

Then I'm importing this file before the `urlpatterns` variable in the `urls.py` file (warned you it was ugly).

What DjangoCMS does is that it tries to find the `Page` with the `Site` given in the request. If the `Page` is not found, DjangoCMS would raise a 404 error, but in our case we re-do the same query but this time without the `Site` filter.

This way a `Page` created on one `Site` is accessible on each sub-`Site`.

I then needed some `Page` accessible on every `Site` with most of the content identical, but SOME different content. I've solved this issue by using the `static_placeholder` tag which can be specified per sub-`Site`. http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#static-placeholder